# VBA - Find and replace multiple values using array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, replace

Below piece of code return " run time error 09 "
This code supposed to find and replace multiple values across worksheet ( removes brackets, replace words etc using fnd - rplc ). List of values to be find are populated in another sheet "Array" List of values to replace populated in another sheet "Array"
I want this code to check all values stored in sheet Array from column E down ( this list can be adjusted ) check if those values are populated inside worksheet "Control Panel" and replace them with values from "Array" column F down.

For below code i did apply "Array" Range but still return error. Any chance to get this running and have array lists flexible, so i can easily add "Find" & "Replace "values

```
Sub Multi_Find_Replace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim fndTable As Range
Dim rplcTable As Range

Set sht = Sheets("Control Panel")
Set fndTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Array").Range("E2:E10")
Set rplcTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Array").Range("F2:F10")

fndList = fndTable
rplcList = rplcTable

  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
      SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `fndTable.Value` when defining the array.

Comment: `fndList` and `rplcList` are 2D arrays, not 1D.

Comment: good point @BigBen. Replace `What:=fndList(x)` with `What:=fndList(x,1)` and the other as well.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman & BigBen thank You both. I manage to apply your tips into my code :)